# How to update product price in database using excel sheet?

Tags: django-rest-framework

I have a task to do.
How to Update a product Price in our database from excel sheet
for eg i have a product name ABC on my website, i want to update that price from an excel sheet

```
class Product(models.Model):
    product_name=models.CharField(max_length=255,blank=True,null=True)
    product_price=models.CharField(max_length=255,blank=True,null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.product_name)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import xlrd

file_path = '.../abc.xls'
wb = xlrd.open_workbook(file_path)
wb_sheet = wb.sheet_by_index(0)
total_rows = wb_sheet.nrows

for rownum in range(1, total_rows):
    product_name = wb_sheet.cell(rownum, 0).value
    product_price = wb_sheet.cell(rownum, 1).value
    if product_name and product_price:
        Product.objects.filter(product_name=product_name).update(product_price=product_price)
```

I assumed product name is in first column and product price is in second column

Comment: Let me if you have any issues

Comment: yes i am not able to put this in my code,can you please help me

Comment: i am a newbie in this

Comment: You can write these code in management command. Read about it here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/custom-management-commands/